# How can I convert big query event_timestamps into PST?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to identify what times my users are starting their sessions. I'm using big query and am having trouble finding an easy solution to convert my timestamp field (event_timestamp, column_type: integer) into an accurate timestamp that is reflected in PST rather than UTC. Any help here would be highly appreciated!

As a note, I have tried using the datetime function in big query to convert, but it doesn't work since the timestamp field itself is an integer and not a timestamp, and when I tried to convert the field into a timestamp, I got a not supported type error.

What I'm looking for is something that can accomplish this:

Select event_date,
event_timestamp,
converted(event_timestamp as PST time)
from table schema
limit 100

Would also be helpful to convert big query's date field into a PST date field as well if possible!

Comment: Hello, may I ask you to provide sample data that you have and the expected output for them? Thank you:)

Comment: Current: 
select event_date, eventimestamp 
from table schema


sample results 
event_date  event_timestamp
20210101   1609773883409000
20210104   1609773886076000


Desired: 
select event_date, 
eventimestamp, converted(event_timestamp as PST time) 
from table schema 
Desired results 
event_date  event_timestamp      converted_timestamp_PST
20210101   1609773883409000   timestamp converted to PST
20210104   1609773886076000  timestamp converted to PST
20210104    1609773886076001  timestamp converted to PST

Comment: You should update your Question instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

This ended up working for me!

```
SELECT distinct 
       event_name
       event_date,
       event_timestamp, 
       cast(event_timestamp as string) as string,
       timestamp_micros(event_timestamp) as timestamp,
       extract(HOUR from (timestamp_micros(event_timestamp))  AT TIME ZONE "America/Los_Angeles") as converted_hour
FROM table_schema
```